# AWS CLI returning error 10060 connection error only on some call(s)

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am using AWS CLI on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\auser>aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.121 Python/2.7.9 Windows/7 botocore/1.5.84
```

Some command works normally, for example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

But if I try `organizations describe-account` I get:

```
C:\Users\auser>aws organizations describe-account --account-id XXXXXXXXXX

('Connection aborted.', error(10060, "Impossible to connect ..."))
```

Note: i am in an enterprise behind a proxy, but i don't think that's a problem since the `describe-instances` works normally

Could it be a permission problem? How could I check on my own?

Comment: http://calvintrobinson.com/resolving-error-10060-when-using-aws-cli-tools-on-your-windows-server/

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a networking issue, most probably on your enterprise's end. Without knowing how your network is setup, it's difficult to troubleshoot. Perhaps there is a maximum amount of connections allowed to go out and sometimes you happen to run up against this limit.

If you want to check your permissions to AWS, assuming you have access to view IAM, you could review the policies affecting whatever user the AWS CLI your machine is configured to work on behalf of.

Comment: if i don't have permission to call: `aws organizations describe-account`, do i get a connection error (10060) ?
And also: how is that possible that aws ec2 describe-instances always works, and organizations describe-account doesn't ? +1 anyway

Comment: That does sound weird. I'm still suspect of the proxy. Shot in the dark, are you using the latest version of the CLI? Also, I did find this, too: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html